# Same search results page on back button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search results page where i have forward link to see next 10 results.
say i have searched some thing and got 90 results then we are showing first 10 results(**1 to 10**) initially, on click on the link we show **10 to 20** and so on.this is happening with out the page load (js). we have a back to search button when you open each results. currently it is assigned as window.history.back which takes to page no 1 though i have navigated from page 4 or 5.
My requirement is to take the user to the same page(resutls) from where he came from, i.e 4 page if he clicks back to search from 42th result.

```
<a id="product-detail-back" onclick="window.history.back();">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

without seeing the code I am assuming the back button refreshes the search.
You might want to look into  working with parameters in url.
for example when you search on google and start moving forward in the results google adds a parameter:

https://www.google.com/search?q=test

moving to the next page brings in:

https://www.google.com/search?q=test#q=test&start=10

That parameter allows to keep track of pages.
If your code then handles getting start as a parameter you could jump to the specific page of your results. once your code handles parameters look into pushState()to research how to push the urls the user goes through to the history